# dojo module inheritance when instantiated within another class

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

Given the following:

### Parent has a ParentsModule:

```
define([ParentsModule,...], 
function(ParentsModule,...) {
    return declare("Parent", ..., {

        someFunction: function(arg) {
            var a = new ParentsModule();
            a.doThis(arg);
        },
        ...
    )};
});
```

### Child extends Parent. Has a ChildsModule

```
define([ChildsModule,Parent,...],
function(ChildsModule,Parent,... ) {
    return declare("Child", [Parent], {

        someFunction: function(arg) {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },
        ...
    )};
});
```

### ParentsModule does it's own thing.

```
define([ParentsModule,...],
function(ParentsModule,... ) {
    return declare("ChildsModule", [ParentsModule], {
        doThis: function(arg) {
            //bunch of stuff happens here.
        },
    ...
    )};
});
```

### ChildsModule extends ParentsModule.

```
define([...],
function(...) {
    return declare("ParentsModule",..., {
        doThis: function(arg) {
            return;
        },
    ...
    )};
});
```

Without editing "Parent", can `a.doThis(arg);` call `ChildsModule.doThis()` instead?

Can I override a module that is instantiated within a function of the parent?

Parent.someFunction has a lot of code I would want to make use of. Parent (and ParentsModule) is a class that has been provided to me, and I am the author of Child (and ChildsModule).

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding the ParentsModule being loaded in the first place, and loading ChildsModule instead?  Of course this would apply to all code that tries to instantiate the ParentsModule - not sure if this is an issue or not.

`var dojoConfig = { paths: { 'orig_code/ParentsModule': 'new_code/ChildsModule' } };`

If you're not familiar with dojoConfig; it needs to be placed somewhere before dojo is loaded.  If you already have one, just add the paths object to it.

Comment: hmmm not sure If I can insert before dojo is loaded.  I'm developing a plugin for a product that includes ParentsModule (and Parent). So I believe my plugin js would be loaded after dojo is loaded.